# onmouseover jquery .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement an onmouseover jquery .animate() effect.  Basically, I have a navigation div and beside it is a hidden (opacity : 0) div.  I'm trying to use the jquery method .animate() to make the hidden div (a submenu) to appear when one of the options is hovered over.

The line of code is here:

```
<li class="b1" onmouseover="function(){$(".subnav1").animate({opacity:1,left:'270px'}, 250, function(){});">
```

The full code is here (css included)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>BEAN - main</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/share.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.7.2.js"></script>   
<style>
body {
    min-width:960px;
}
.container{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:960px;
    margin-left:-480px;
}
.topbar{
    width:960px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.mainnav{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Share', cursive;
    left:160px;
    width:110px;
    height:140px;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
}
.subnav1{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Share', cursive;
    left:290px;
    width:110px;
    height:140px;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
}
.subnav2{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Share', cursive;
    left:290px;
    width:110px;
    height:140px;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
}
.subnav3{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Share', cursive;
    left:290px;
    width:110px;
    height:140px;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
}
.language{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    left:740px;
    width:220px;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:140px;
    float:left;
}
ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
li{
    display:list-item;
    text-align:left;
}
A:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
A:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
A:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
A:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="topbar"></div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="140px" height="140px" /></div>
    <div class="mainnav">
        <ul>
            <li class="b1" onmouseover="function(){$(".subnav1").animate({opacity:1,left:'270px'}, 250, function(){});">
                <a href="#">about me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="b2">
                <a href="#">photography</a>
            </li>
            <li class="b3">
                <a href="#">urban planning</a>
            </li>
            <li class="b4">
                <a href="#">graphic design</a>
            </li>
            <li class="b5">
                <a href="#">my blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav1">
        <ul id="sub1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Facts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Values</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav2">
        <ul id="sub2">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Photostream</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">The Map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav3">
        <ul id="sub3">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Essay Collection</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">The City Project</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="language">
    blah
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be solved by css unless it is necessary to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ds8k/)

For best practice use the html markup like this.

```
<div class="mainnav">
        <ul>
            <li class="b1">
                <a href="#">about me</a>
                 <ul id="sub1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Facts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Values</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="b2">
                <a href="#">photography</a>
                <ul id="sub2">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Photostream</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">The Map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="b3">
                <a href="#">urban planning</a>
            </li>
            <li class="b4">
                <a href="#">graphic design</a>
            </li>
            <li class="b5">
                <a href="#">my blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

​This code works to show hide the sub menu

```
$(".mainnav li").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').fadeOut();
});​
```

Comment: Hmm..... It doesn't seem to work.  I have the script just at the bottom of the </body>...  Would it be possible for you to show the implementation on the code I provided in the first post? Thanks!